# ASP.NET core high memory consume

Tags: asp.net-core

I have some ASP.NET core project and I was looking on memory that consumes. I just get terrified by it. It's not a that big project. I have a few controllers and it consumes about 350MB of Ram and that's a big amount of memory for the webserver.

My question is can I somehow reduce it? One idea that I have is to you struct instead of a model for Data Relation Model, but that will not reduce that that mutch as I want to. Are some other ways, I like to try them all :)

And the last thing, I now ASP.NET core is a very complex framework, that means I wont to use it for small Project this is just for education purposes. and last question: is the memory big problem?

Screenshot of my project:
[image: Screenshot 1]

my bigger controller :)

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RustWiki.Data;
using RustWiki.Models.WikiViewModels;

namespace RustWiki.Controllers.api
{
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TableManagerController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public TableManagerController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    //Get
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/ArmorTypes")]
    public IActionResult GetArmorTypes() => Ok(_context.ArmorTypes.ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Cloating")]
    public IActionResult GetCloating() => Ok(_context.Cloating.Include(c => c.ArmorType).Include(c => c.Defencis).Include(c => c.Item.ItemType).ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Defencis")]
    public IActionResult GetDefences() => Ok(_context.Defencis.ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Dmgs")]
    public IActionResult GetDmg() => Ok(_context.Dmgs.ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Equipment")]
    public IActionResult GetEquipment() => Ok(_context.Equipment.Include(e => e.Dmg).Include(e => e.Item.ItemType).ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Items")]
    public IActionResult GetItems() => Ok(_context.Items.Include(i => i.ItemType).ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/ItemTypes")]
    public IActionResult GetItemType() => Ok(_context.ItemTypes.ToList());

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Resources")]
    public IActionResult GetResource() => Ok(_context.Resources.ToList());

    //Delete

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/ArmourTypes/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelArmourType(int id) => Delete(_context.ArmorTypes, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Cloating/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelCloating(int id) => Delete(_context.Cloating, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Defences/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelDefencis(int id) => Delete(_context.Defencis, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Dmgs/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelDmg(int id) => Delete(_context.Dmgs, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Equipments/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelEquipment(int id) => Delete(_context.Equipment, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Items/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelItem(int id) => Delete(_context.Items, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/ItemTypes/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelItemType(int id) => Delete(_context.ItemTypes, id);

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/api/Resources/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DelResource(int id) => Delete(_context.Resources, id);

    private IActionResult Delete<T>(DbSet<T> set, int id) where T : class
    {
        var obj = set.SingleOrDefault(delegate (T o)
        {
            return (o as IWikiModel)?.Id == id;
        });
        if (obj == null)
            return NotFound();
        set.Remove(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(obj);
    }

    //Create

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/ArmourType")]
    public IActionResult CreateArmourType([FromBody]ArmorType type)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}    
}
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: You shouldn't be worried too much, ASP.NET Core uses many caches for improved performance. Caches are heavily used for parsing of the request process (i.e. headers) to avoid allocation and collecting of memory and you shouldn't worry about it unless it consumes unreasonably high amount of memory (in range of GB). During beta the biggest bottle neck in performance benchmarks was the allocation and garbage collection involved with every request. And last but not least, memory is cheap these days

Comment: @Tseng i was looking on lots of sources and that was a bit confusing
 for me, but now I'm clear. Thank you very mutch.

Comment: I am finding a simple asp.net core 2.x site is using ~250mb ram.  This is a serious amount or ram (compared to .net 4.6x).  I was hosting on cloud and I noticed this first as my app pool was constantly recycling at 300mb limit.  Is this normal and to be expected?

Comment: @David I just saw your comment after posting almost the exact same comment on the answer to this question.  I'm seeing the same challenge -- always going to over 300MB.  I'm wondering what the baseline RAM usage would be for dotnet core. It seems like it is 300 & greater.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say that your API is consuming a lot of memory, is it really? What benchmarking are you currently doing? Are you running it locally and looking at memory consumption? If so, there are a lot more things running in `Debug` than just your application code like debug symbols that will increase the memory footprint of a seemingly small application.

If you do need to hunt down memory leaks or high consumption (this is a metric specific to your situation) then use a tried and tested profiler like [ANTS Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwv73VBRCdARIsAOnG8u2r5KFJRWRm2CadOvUu0sgb8D8Q8t0_CO7_GycWJiNQyf24sljJqUMaAnlNEALw_wcB).

**EDIT**: [looking at memory management and GC for .NETCore 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> When an ASP.NET Core app starts, the GC:
>
> Reserves some memory for the initial heap segments.
> Commits a small portion of memory when the runtime is loaded.
>
> The preceding memory allocations are done for performance reasons. The performance benefit comes from heap segments in contiguous memory.

Furthermore, the GC mode Server GC (default) or Workstation GC has a large impact on the application's memory usage.

> The working set drops from 500 MB to 70 MB.
>
> The GC does generation 0 collections multiple times per second instead of every two seconds.
>
> GC drops from 300 MB to 10 MB.

In most cases Server GC is the ideal option. However, for small app's not expecting much traffic then GC mode should be considered.

Although it may seem like a basic app is consuming a lot of memory, the important thing here is that the GC grabs a chunk of contiguous memory when the app starts.

Meaning once your app starts there is already reserved memory for your user objects and the run-time doesn't need to request more from the OS. Provided the app does not leak memory, memory usage would remain stable as objects are allocated and collected.

Comment: Thanks a lot a has trying it in debug in VS Comunity like is on the screen. I think all the project consuming lots of memory like 350MB in debug. i afreid if i was create a new project it was consuming abouth 80 to 100MB of RAM and I was afreid of bigger projects. thats all abouth that :)

Comment: I'm running a basic .NET Core 6.x app on a webhost. This is just a project created from the most basic template ($ dotnet core new mvc -o ProjName)  My webhost continually shows that this app eats up over 300MB ram.  I'm attempting to figure out why this would be true.  I'm running it OutOfProcess.  What should the baseline RAM usage be for such a simple project?

Comment: @raddevus, looking at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0, 300MB seems normal for a server GC mode. Assuming 300MB of contiguous memory reserved for the GC, your memory usage wouldn't necessarily grow as user-space objects are allocated and collected.