# ASP.NET MVC enormous memory usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app with approx. 12k buyable items in a SQL database. The memory usage after the start of the app is +- 250mb.

The problem occurs when I navigate to shopall section when the items are listed. Once opened memory usage raise 200mb. I've implemented paging and each page of items clicked adds another 200mb of memory usage, which stacks up to **2.2GB** of usage:

[image: usage].

The question is, how much memory usage is optimal for online shop with 10-13k of items in it.

Is there anything I can do to cut off memory usage, or is it just better to write app from scratch if so what should I be concerned about from the start?

Shop all controller along with service

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShopAll(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 60)
{
        var (items, totalCount) = await _context.GetAll(pageNumber, pageSize);
        var viewModel = new ShopAllVM
        {
            Items = items,
            CategoryNames = await _searchService.GetCategoryNames(),
            PerkNames = await _searchService.GetPerksNames(),
            CurrentPage = pageNumber,
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalCount / (double)pageSize)
        };

    return View(viewModel);
}

public async Task<(IEnumerable<Item>, int totalCount)> GetAll(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var totalCount = await _context.Item.CountAsync();
    var items = await _context.Item
         .Include(c => c.Categories)
         .Include(p => p.Promotion)
         .Include(o => o.Opinions)
         .Include(d => d.Perks)
         .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
         .Take(pageSize)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .ToListAsync();

    return (items, totalCount);
}
```

`ShopAll` view in razor is bsc generating div `@foreach` every item, nothing fancy.

Comment: Nothing looks too "off".  But I wonder about that `_context` object. I assume it's an EF `DbContext` object.  Are you storing that in session rather than re-creating it for every page call?  Are you disposing of it after use?

Comment: @Ann L. So you are telling me this kind of usage is not as bad as it seems to be? I don't manually dispose dbcontext, it is registered as a scoped service and the dispose should be done automatically by the .net core shouldnt it? Should i do in manually. If so, how?

Comment: I think the memory usage is very surprising, but I don't see anything in your code that looks too "off". That's what I meant!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about .NET Core and scoped services (I work mostly on legacy .NET code) so I can't be of help there.

Comment: I do think the most likely culprit is the DbContext holding on to the objects it has retrieved, because there's just not that many other candidates in your code!  But, beyond that, I'm afraid I can't be much help. You might try using the performance monitoring features of VS: they can be very helpful with memory problems.

Comment: One thought I just had, though:  if you repeatedly load the SAME page of items, does the memory usage go up as fast? That would tell us something!

Comment: @Ann L. well yes, it does!

Comment: [This is probably a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371025/asp-net-core-high-memory-consume) about your same problem. Look at it and in particular pay attention to the profiler usage part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET core high memory consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371025/asp-net-core-high-memory-consume)